# What is the best way to avoid SpamCop trigger a ASP.NET web page?

Tags: hosting, spam, suspend

Good Days,

I have recently developed a web application in ASP.NET for a marketer that he has been sending emails to his potential customers to fill out a web form existing in this ASP.NET application.

Recently, he received an email from his hosting company saying that they will suspend his account because his emails were triggered by SpamCop. He basically put a link to that web form in the email messages.

What would be the best way to handle this situation? Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks,

Niyazi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to avoid being labeled as a spammer is to **not send spam emails**.  Emailing random people and asking them to visit your website and fill out a form is spam, plain and simple.

I would suggest finding a less evil way of getting hits on a website like a [Google Adwords campaign](http://www.google.com/ads/adwords/).

Also, for your convenience, I have included the first link in my google search of `"How to drive traffic to your website."`

http://sbinfocanada.about.com/cs/ecommerce/a/drivetrafficmm.htm

Please pay attention to #3

Comment: Thank you for your time and response Robert.

Answer (score 1):

Don't send spam?

Incidentally, how does your web app fit into this?  Is your app sending the emails?  If so, read up on the [CAN-SPAM act](http://www.ftc.gov/bcp/edu/pubs/business/ecommerce/bus61.shtm).

Getting yourself removed from SpamCops blacklist will probably be hard given that it sounds like you were actually sending spam.